# How to create a drilling simulation?

Tags: animation

I want to show a dental turbine drilling into a tooth . I can't  create the effect of the surface being ripped up by the turbine. I want to animate the shavings of the surface, to give it a realistic appearance .
I've created all what i need ( teeth bones turbine and instruments...)  I can do the basic animation, but I can't figure out how to have the section of the tooth be removed after drilling . 
This is an exemple for what i want  to create : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmiMQDZFSQY&index=52&list=WL

[image]

Comment: i am new on blender . and i am looking to create educational videos of dental medicine and i have difficulties in the simulation of the drilling

Comment: What problem do you have exactly? What you've done so far?

Comment: Do you mean something like this?: https://youtu.be/NAXGQNwRUfk?t=17

Comment: The hardest part of this project is going to be the video **tape** part of it...

Comment: @cegaton LOL :D

Comment: @PaulGonet yes exactely (y)

Comment: @cegaton you make fun of me or what ??? . my english is not very good . i thought that you are an educated person . i didn't think you are too arrogant

Comment: @romax sorry for that, what I meant is that video tape is a technology that hardly anyone uses today. I didn't mean to disrespect you.

Comment: I think using shape keys and particles may do the job.